# How to get email.message_from_bytes to work with unicode input

Tags: python, email, unicode, emoji

When `email.message_from_bytes()` is given input with unicode/emoji in the headers, the resulting output results in unexpected TypeErrors. Is it possible to process the input (encoding, decoding, etc) before passing it to `message_from_bytes()` to prevent these TypeErrors?

The overall goal is to get [gyb.py](https://github.com/GAM-team/got-your-back) to successfully clean + restore backups from gyb-generated .eml files, some of which contain unicode/emoji in the email headers. Also the unicode/emoji should be preserved without mangling them (like in the sample output.)

Minimal reproduction:

```
import email
f = open('./sample.eml', 'rb')
bytes = f.read()
message = email.message_from_bytes(bytes)

# No unicode/emoji: works as expected:
print(message['to'])
print(len(message['to']))

# With unicode/emoji: unexpected TypeError:
print(message['from'])
print(len(message['from']))
```

sample.eml

```
To: recipient <to@example.com>
From:sender <from@example.com>
```

output:

```
$ python check-message.py
recipient <to@example.com>
26
����sender���� <from@example.com>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "V:\gyb\jkm\check-message.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(len(message['from']))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: object of type 'Header' has no len()
```

---

Github issues related to larger gyb restore problem

- https://github.com/GAM-team/got-your-back/issues/433
- https://github.com/GAM-team/got-your-back/issues/432

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `email.message_from_bytes` with [policy `email.policy.SMTPUTF8`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.policy.html#email.policy.SMTPUTF8).

```
import email, email.policy
with open('./sample.eml', 'rb') as f:
    message = email.message_from_bytes(f.read(), policy=email.policy.SMTPUTF8)

    print(message['from'])
    print(len(message['from']))
```

This successfully outputs:

```
sender <from@example.com>
27
```